# Grouping duplicates in a csv file

Tags: scala, csv

I have a CSV file which I've applied a case class onto and made into a list e.g

CSV file was like this -

```
"user_id","age","liked_ad","location"
2145,34,true,USA
6786,25,true,UK
9025,21,false,USA
1145,40,false,UK
```

It goes on. Ultimately I am trying to find the top user_id's who have the most liked_ad's (true values). I know that there are duplicates within the csv file as I did -

```
val origFile = processCSV("src/main/resources/advert-data.csv")
val origFileLength = origFile.length

val uniqueList = origFile.distinct
val uniqueListLength = uniqueList.length
```

The two lengths were different. I am thinking I need to group all the user_id's so that all the entries of the same user_id are in a group where I can then count how many 'trues' are in that user's entries. I am completely stuck on the right way to go about this.

This is my processCSV function at the moment -

```
final case class AdvertInfo(userId: Int, age: Int, likedAd: Boolean, location: String)

    def processCSV(file: String): List[AdvertInfo] = {
      val data = io.Source.fromFile(file)

      data
        .getLines()
        .map(_.split(',').iterator.map(_.trim).toList)
        .flatMap {
          case userIdRaw :: ageRaw :: likedAdRaw :: locationRaw :: Nil =>
            for {
              userId <- userIdRaw.toIntOption
              age <- ageRaw.toIntOption
              likedAd <- likedAdRaw.toBooleanOption
              location <- Some(locationRaw)
            } yield AdvertInfo(userId, age, likedAd, location)
          case _ =>
            None
        }.toList
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your description is a bit confusing but I think what you want is:

```
origFile.filter(_.likedAd)
        .groupMapReduce(_.userId)(_ => 1)(_+_) //Scala 2.13.x
```

The result is a `Map` with the `user_id`s as the keys and the count of all the `liked_ad`=="true" as the values.

From there you can `.toList.sortBy(-_._2)` in order to get the ranking-by-liked-count.

Comment: Hi when I try to filter the origFile I am getting 'Cannot resolve overloaded method'

Comment: @monkeys73; If `origFile` is type `List[AdvertInfo]` (which is what `processCSV()` is _supposed_ to return) then I see no reason why the compiler should be confused. That `filter()` call works for me just as described.